# Java Drag & Drop and Cloneable

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlabel, cloneable

I have this problem to solve where you have a `JPanel` and `JLabel` and you have to clone `JLabel` with drag and drop and create a `JLabel` clone on the `JPanel` where `JLabel` was dropped. First thing I'd like to ask is if it's possible to implement `Cloneable` interface to `JLabel` in anonymous class like listeners, so I don't have to write my own class that extends `JLabel` and implements `Cloneable`. I know how to drag and drop `JLabel` to `JTextField` by transfering "text" property, but I have no idea how to clone a `JLabel` to `JPanel`.

Comment: `if it's possible to implement Cloeable interface to JLabel in anonymous class like listeners, so I don't have to write my own class that extends JLabel and implements Cloneable`. By doing an anonymous class you are already writting your own class... it is just that you just don't name it

Comment: I ment if it's possible to do it like: label.addSomething(new Cloneable(){...});

Comment: No! No! No! and a thousand No!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing the `Cloneable` interface is unlikely to achieve any beneficial effect in this context. In [*Effective Java, Second Edition*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), the author outlines the vagaries of cloning objects in *Item 11: Override clone judiciously*.

[*Drag and Drop*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) transfers the data, not the container. Because `String` is immutable, there's no reason to clone a `String` at all. For mutable data, a copy constructor or factory method makes more sense.

Because `JLabel` is not user editable, it may be an unexpected target for DnD, although it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9498321/230513). Alternatively, you can add a [suitable component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/defaultsupport.html) at run time using the container's `add()` method, followed by `validate()` and `repaint()`.

Comment: @kleopatra: I'm not sure. The label's text is programmatically mutable, but the content cannot be edited _in situ_ by the user. For example, `JTable` might render with a `JLabel` but edit using a `JTextField`. I wouldn't think to target a label, but I'd welcome your insight. Please don't hesitate to edit the answer as needed.

Comment: we are talking dragging, if I understand the OP correctly (the question is a bit cloudy :-). Me thinking along the lines of a property transferHandler, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486118/java-drag-drop-imageicon-from-jlabel-on-panel-1-to-jlabel-on-panel-2 but with text property instead of icon property. If so, its text can be dragged onto any component with a text property, independent of that component having the notion of editability. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: @kleopatra: Your point is well-taken. I've tried to clarify above. Thank you for taking time for critical review.